# How to setup a solr cluster (v4.9.1) with implicit routing

Tags: solr

I'm a newbie for Solr and trying to create a solr (v4.9.1) cluster and add new shards on the go. But it is not enabling me to create new shard giving below error. Please assist.

```
*INFO  - 2018-11-12 13:17:20.603; org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/collections params={name=<collection-name>_shard1&action=CREATESHARD&collection=<collection-name>} status=400 QTime=28 
INFO  - 2018-11-12 13:18:11.664; org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler; Create shard: name=<collection-name>_shard1&action=CREATESHARD&collection=<collection-name>&shard=shard1
```

ERROR - 2018-11-12 13:18:11.665; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: shards can be added only to 'implicit' collections
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleCreateShard(CollectionsHandler.java:503)*

Comment: It doesn't sound like your collection actually uses implicit routing - have you verified that this is the case? And have you tried a more recent version of Solr instead? 4.9.x is ancient by now, and there's _a lot_ of improvements in the cluster area since 4.x.

Comment: My client is requesting v4.9.1. So I can't use newer version for this. I know solr provides a different routing as a default.